# JPanel con setvisible=true no se muestra cuando lo llamo desde el Main()

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica a  un programa que tengo. Pide varios datos al usuario, este los rellena, y con esos datos usa una funcion que registra los datos en un fichero. 
No tengo problema para ver como es el JPanel desde el Designer:
[image]

Tengo ya hecho el actionlistener y todo, pero cuando desde el main llamo al JPanel, no sale nada.
Mi clase JPanel es:

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener
```

Que usa:

```
public Menu() {
```

Y ahí está todo.
Pero cuando desde el main hago:

```
Menu algo = new Menu();
    algo.setVisible(true);
```

Compila sin problemas, comienza, pero no sale nada de nada...y en la consola pone "aplicacion terminada"...

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos vamos desde el principio parece que disenaste tu panel desde el disenador que da netbeans o eclipse pero aun asi sigue siendo un jpanel clasico por lo tanto necesita un JFrame para poder visualizarse.

En tu caso le puedes creas el JFrame desde el disenador o desde codigo, en este caso yo lo voy ha hacer desde codigo y le voy agregar el panel que previamente has creado tu.

```
public class WMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu menu=new Menu();
        JFrame mainWindow=new JFrame("Menu sample");

        mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainWindow.add(menu);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: perfecto era eso! El JPanel lo hice con WindowBuilder para Eclipse, no con NetBeans ;)

Comment: @KekaBron Que bueno que te sirvio, ya corregi el texto.

Answer (score 0):

falta agregar tamano de tu componente, por que sin tamano no se visualizara nada.

```
ejemplo
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setbounds(poX,posY,tamX,tamY);
```

nota:talves tambien falte usar un layout para la organizacion de los elementos